# Couldn't make Angry birds work on wine

Tags: wine

I can run Notepad++ the Angry bird exe is not working. Whenever I open the exe, I see one of my screens flicker a bit (as lines and not the whole screen) and nothing happens. Any ideas?

Edit: Output of `wine angrybirds.exe`

```
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.VC80.CRT" (8.0.50727.4053)
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.VC90.CRT" (9.0.21022.8)
err:module:import_dll Library MSVCP90.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\AppUpWrapper.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library AppUpWrapper.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\angrybirds.exe") not found
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\\windows\\system32\\angrybirds.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

I think it didn't even install. I manually dropped those files in the folder but still no gain.

**Edit: Progress**

I dropped the file **MSVCP90.dll** manually and now this is what I get in the output

```
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.VC80.CRT" (8.0.50727.4053)
fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.VC90.CRT" (9.0.21022.8)
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation 0x541000 0 0x32fd48 4
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
EXCEPTION: Failed to open data/scripts/starLimits.lua
wine: Unhandled exception 0x40000015 at address 0x7b880023:0x78b271d0 (thread 0009), starting debugger...
fixme:msvcr90:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x10267694) stub
fixme:msvcr90:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x78506644) stub
ashfame@ashfame-desktop:~$ Process of pid=0008 has terminated
No process loaded, cannot execute 'echo Modules:'
Cannot get info on module while no process is loaded
No process loaded, cannot execute 'echo Threads:'
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000011 winedevice.exe
    00000018    0
    00000016    0
    00000013    0
    00000012    0
00000019 explorer.exe
    0000001a    0
You must be attached to a process to run this command.
No process loaded, cannot execute 'detach'
```

and there the terminal hangs (I mean I would have to Ctrl + C to get out). It shows up the famous message, that it needs to close down.

I don't use wine for anything else, so I am ready to do a clean install of wine and everything if anyone is willing to provide me instructions.

**Resolved**

As per the marked correct answer by @DoR, I did a `mv ~/.wine ~/wine.bak` and then re-ran the game and it worked. So basically it was something wrong in the wine install. :)

Comment: can you add the output of `wine angrybirds.exe | output.txt`?

Comment: @Roland Please check the output

Comment: You may still be missing dlls, such as MVC8, maybe a dependency checker might be able to find the missing dlls (sorry I forgot the name of the most popular one that works on wine).

Comment: @Roland So what can I do for a clean and stable wine setup?

Comment: the problem is not a clean and stable wine setup here, though that might help. WINE misses a lot of dlls, not sure why, but it it does. What you can do is delete `~/.wine` (NB: YOU WILL LOSE ALL WINE APPLICATIONS SHOULD YOU DO THIS) and start from scratch, or you could install vineyard and use it to create a new wine bottle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add the [PPA for Ubuntu Wine Team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
   ```
2. Install the `wine1.3` package. Just running Update Manager won't install it as it is a different package than `wine1.2` (the version of Wine included in the repositories).

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install wine1.3
   ```
3. Double-click on `AngryBirds.exe` or in a terminal run the command:

   ```
   wine AngryBirds.exe
   ```

   If this still doesn't work, try backing up and removing your `~/.wine` directory:

   ```
   mv ~/.wine ~/.wine.bak
   ```
4. Kill some green pigs:

   [image]

Comment: @DoR How do I completely remove it first? I installed the one from repositories so I think its 1.2

Comment: @Ashfame, `sudo apt-get remove wine1.2`? I already had the wine from the repositories installed when I install wine1.3 and I didn't need to remove it.

Comment: @DoR Sadly that didn't work. I am having the same errors with `wine AngryBirds.exe` as I have in my question along with a few more.

Comment: @Ashfame What does `wine --version` say?

Comment: @DoR wine-1.3.14

Comment: @Ashfame try moving your wine directory: `cp -r ~/.wine ~/wine.bak` and launching it again.

Comment: @DoR and after that? Try re-running?

Comment: @Ashfame yes. <15 chars>

Comment: @DoR Nothing new! What was supposed to happened with the copying of files?

Comment: @Ashfame Doh! Sorry, I meant to write `mv` (move) instead of `cp` (copy). Replace `cp` with `mv` and try again.

Comment: Awesome mate! It works now. :)

Comment: @Ashfame :) Edited my answer to include that last command.

Comment: I added that in the question too. Thanks a lot buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the wine ppa (ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa) to your software sources and upgrade wine to the latest version. This should make Angry Birds work well.

Comment: I have them added and already did a sudo apt-get update

Answer (score 1):

I had same troble. Solved it very easely:
when you install "Angry birds" just check Microsoft Visual C++ redistribitible package

Answer (score 1):

This error may occur when missing "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package". To fix it

1. Identify the version that you need to install from
   ' L"Microsoft.VC80.CRT" (8.0.50727.4053) ' (brackets containing
   version)
2. Pick correct version from [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5766) to download.
3. Then just download it and install using wine.

   You will see the success!