# Crysis 2 Demo on Wine error

Tags: 10.10, wine, games

I was trying to install the Crysis 2 demo on wine, but after extraction it said

```
Unable to find a volume for file extraction.  
Please verify that you have proper permissions.
```

and ended the setup there.

[image]

[image]

I have had trouble in the past getting Angry birds to run on it too - [Couldn't make Angry birds work on wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25473/couldnt-make-angry-birds-to-work-on-wine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use #[winetricks](http://packages.ubuntu.com/winetricks) [image: Install winetricks] and install the VC++ packages :).

Comment: all of them? http://img6.imagebanana.com/img/wl150pf8/Winetricks_030.png

Comment: I would suggest installing the most recent, but I often install all of them to be safe.

Comment: which one is the latest? vcrun2010 I guess? or the other two following it

Comment: I believe 2010 is the latest, but you might want to install the others to maximize support for most windows applications.

Comment: Thanks, trying other VC++ packages helped. vcrun2010 wouldn't install, was giving error with wget and then it would abort the installation.